# S22 Wifi Hotspot/USB Tether/Ethernet Tether not working

Tags: samsung, tethering

I have a Samsung S22 and i was trying to share the internet connection to my PC but i tried wifi hotspot/usb/ethernet tether but none of them is working,on the PC it says Connected and Internet Access but website wouldnt load and had a "The Site Can't be reached" error. I tried  connecting to my laptop and ipad too, same problem.I vaguely remember i tried to do the same thing previously and it didnt work too so i use my backup phone using the same sim card and i think it worked?